# Hide title bar if it's not an ActionBar - predict ActionBar presence before setContentView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-windowmanager

If my fullscreen preference (off by default) is on, I want my Activity to hide the title bar as well as the notification bar. I can do that with `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` + `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` etc. or perhaps `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);`

Either of these must happen **before** `setContentView()` or they will crash. The hard part is:

- I target API levels 3 to 14, and I only want to hide the title bar if the Activity is not going to use an ActionBar. Otherwise, `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` will hide the ActionBar and lose some important controls. (I'll instead settle for "lights-out" mode.)
- I can't see how to find out whether an ActionBar will be used until **after** `setContentView()`, when it's too late.

Things that don't work:

- `getActionBar()` returns null at this early stage.
- `getWindow.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` is false.
- Knowing (by reflection) that ActionBar exists as a class is insufficient, because, sticking with the default device theme, that might not always use ActionBar on some Ice Cream Sandwich devices, even though the platform has it. (?)

  - Alternatively: can I rely on ICS always having an ActionBar? Why?
  - Edit: ok, maybe ICS' title bar is still an ActionBar, just with no items and not even the overflow button? (In which case I still want to hide it.) Can anyone shed any light there?

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use instead is [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It takes care of all the reflection and API level detection for you.

Comment: Sorry, no. Need to support API level 3 (Android 1.5) as I said, and that's 1.6+ - but I will definitely keep it in mind for future projects. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. just curious, why do you need to support 1.5?

Comment: Because Android Market says I have 1200 users on 1.5.

Comment: Accepting this answer - that number is now more like 200, and I don't think 1.5 is worth caring about these days (even the G1 got up to 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to do something like suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme)? Basically specify that on certain api levels, you hide the title bar (because you will have the action bar).

Comment: I can certainly vary my choice of Theme, but that doesn't really solve the ICS problem: I can see in the emulator that ICS phones have a title bar (or an ActionBar that doesn't receive any items or even the overflow button), which I want to hide, and ICS tablets have an ActionBar, which I want to keep. A Theme will still hide both or neither as far as I can tell, and I can't tell whether the platform is going to use an ActionBar. I think those links were written before ICS and assume that always keeping the title bar in Honeycomb onwards is ok, where I actually want to hide it on phones.

Comment: Would it be possible to specify this with `-small` and `-large` tags for your configurations as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669836/android-conditional-layouts-for-phonestablets)?

Comment: If I could rely on the OS using a (non-empty) ActionBar if and only if the device is in the "large" category, then yes. But those categories are deprecated from 3.2 up http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html so I doubt they're what the OS is using.